# How do I fix my Commerce Feeds import process post updating my modules and core?

Tags: commerce, feeds

I have just upgraded to core 7.15 and updated all my modules at the same time.
When I now try and run the an import using commerce feeds I receive the error below.

```
    An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
    HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. 
    Path: /batch?id=892&op=do 
    StatusText: OK 
    ResponseText: Fatal error: 
Call to undefined function commerce_product_validate_sku() in /home/mmlcofdk/public_html/sites/all/modules/commerce_feeds/plugins/FeedsCommerceProductProcessor.inc on line 216
```

I would really appreciate some advice on how I could go about debugging this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. I think that is because I am using a old version Drupal Commerce and it is incompatible the newer version of Feeds module that i am using.

but I manage to get it work by paste in this function:

```
function commerce_product_validate_sku($sku) {
  // Do not allow commas in a SKU.
  if (strpos($sku, ',')) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

into the file "commerce_prouduct.module" located in:

```
{mydrupal-installation}\profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\commerce\modules\product
```

I found that function in:

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product!commerce_product.module/7

Hope that help!

Apollo Tang

Comment: It hasn't made any difference for me. I am still getting the same error. But I am not using the Commerce Quick Start installation, so I applied the fix in /public_html/sites/all/modules/commerce/modules/product/commerce_product.module

Comment: Oops. Looks like I lied. It does seem to have fixed things. Thanks so much! Must have been the cache?